# How to use var_dump in joomla

Tags: php, joomla2.5, var-dump

My question might be little silly but please bear with me. I suppose var_dump should work anywhere in the code which calls its service but unfortunately i can't return anything if i use it in a controller, or model. ya it does work in the view/layout page.

I tried testing the following simple thing in one of my controller function and it returns nothing;

```
$foo = "bar";
var_dump($foo);
```

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Joomla, but in an MVC framework, the view expects data to come from the controller in a particular format, perhaps JSON or XML. When you call `var_dump()`, it will most likely mess up the syntax of this, so the application won't work. When you're debugging with this tool, you'll want to make use of the browser's console (Developer Tools or Firebug) to view what was returned. Go into the Network tab, select the URL of the controller, and then view the response data. There you'll see the output of `var_dump()`.

Comment: @raaman try `exit(var_dump($foo));` . it will stop while executing code and print the results.

Answer (score 0):

For show a variable and pause the executing you have 3 options.

```
echo $variable;
print_r($variable);
var_dump($variable);
```

and you need to write die() after them to stop code and show your $variable.